# Filter array of objects by property in nested array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, multidimensional-array

```js
import { AdminService } from 'src/app/services/admin.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Player } from './player.model';
import { LoggerService } from 'src/app/services/logger.service';
import {Sort} from '@angular/material';
import { last, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-players',
  templateUrl: './players.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./players.page.scss'],
})

export class PlayersPage implements OnInit {

data = [{ "_id" : { "id" : ObjectId("5cc99406babc4817f85c707e"), "email" : "juliatyles@gmail.com" }, "buyer" : [ "juliatyles@gmail.com" ], "event" : "COED A", "field" : "Main", "net" : null, "team" : null, "player" : { "overallRanking" : { "CoedRanking" : 17, "CoedRankingG" : 17, "Ranking" : 25, "RankingG" : 40 }, "shirtSize" : "S", "ranking" : { "PoolCAAG" : 31, "PoolCBB" : 17, "PoolCOpenG" : 9, "PoolWA" : 22, "PoolWAA" : 3, "PoolWOpenG" : 40 }, "avp_id" : "1013424", "adult" : true, "country" : "united states", "zip" : "10924", "state" : "ny", "city" : "goshen", "address" : "4 Maple Ave", "phone" : "8452589229", "email" : "juliatyles@gmail.com", "last" : "Tyles", "first" : "Julia", "completed" : true, "waivers" : ObjectId("5cc98496babc4817f85c6f65") }, "waivers" : [ { "url" : [ "https://waiverstevie.koptional.com/form/v7/juliatyles@gmail.com/9CYPpy1Cwa14SzS5uCb7ULX4q1HtEjvWnHYlOT3K" ], "message" : [ "Liability Waiver" ], "has_signed" : [ true ], "signatureUrl" : [ "https://s3.amazonaws.com/formsign.storage/public/signed/oqPxjdKjAUlWIqNbqtMz37Iu1FdbasvQhmvomen2.pdf" ], "email" : [ "juliatyles@gmail.com" ] } ] }
{ "_id" : { "id" : ObjectId("5cc99406babc4817f85c707e"), "email" : "lewiseric343@yahoo.com" }, "buyer" : [ "juliatyles@gmail.com" ], "event" : "COED A", "field" : "Main", "net" : null, "team" : null, "player" : { "overallRanking" : { "CoedRanking" : 32, "CoedRankingG" : 32, "Ranking" : 4 }, "shirtSize" : "XL", "ranking" : { "PoolCA" : 14, "PoolCAAG" : 7, "PoolCBB" : 17, "PoolMAA" : 3 }, "avp_id" : "1018083", "adult" : true, "country" : "united stated ", "zip" : "10924", "state" : "ny", "city" : "goshen", "address" : "4 Maple Ave", "phone" : "8452757319", "email" : "lewiseric343@yahoo.com", "last" : "lewis", "first" : "eric", "completed" : true, "waivers" : ObjectId("5cc99407babc4817f85c707f") }, "waivers" : [ { "url" : [ "https://waiverstevie.koptional.com/form/v7/lewiseric343@yahoo.com/vT15NATFszkaoy2h4KQbcW0KBMYyMLQlB6GONPIa" ], "message" : [ "Liability Waiver" ], "has_signed" : [ false ], "signatureUrl" : [ ], "email" : [ "lewiseric343@yahoo.com" ] } ] }
{ "_id" : { "id" : ObjectId("5cc994c6babc4817f85c7096"), "email" : "axacast22@aol.com" }, "buyer" : [ "axa_to@yahoo.com" ], "event" : "COED A", "field" : "Main", "net" : null, "team" : null, "player" : { "shirtSize" : "L", "avp_id" : "1035488", "adult" : true, "country" : "United States", "zip" : "07410", "state" : "NJ", "city" : "Fair Lawn", "address" : "45 26Th Street", "phone" : "2016757924", "email" : "axacast22@aol.com", "last" : "Duran", "first" : "Jesus", "completed" : true, "waivers" : ObjectId("5cc994c6babc4817f85c7097") }, "waivers" : [ { "url" : [ "https://waiverstevie.koptional.com/form/v7/axacast22@aol.com/LFSV6Cf02Gf2aqGZkbLr9lNWzWOuUWKzt42i5Xom" ], "message" : [ "Liability Waiver" ], "has_signed" : [ false ], "signatureUrl" : [ ], "email" : [ "axacast22@aol.com" ] }, { "url" : [ "https://waiverstevie.koptional.com/form/v7/axacast22@aol.com/LFSV6Cf02Gf2aqGZkbLr9lNWzWOuUWKzt42i5Xom" ], "message" : [ "Liability Waiver" ], "has_signed" : [ false ], "signatureUrl" : [ ], "email" : [ "axacast22@aol.com" ] } ] }
{ "_id" : { "id" : ObjectId("5cc99781babc4817f85c70b8"), "email" : "kevin.c.cole@gmail.com" }, "buyer" : [ "kevinccole@gmail.com" ], "event" : "COED A", "field" : "Main", "net" : null, "team" : null, "player" : { "completed" : true, "first" : "Kevin", "last" : "Cole", "email" : "kevin.c.cole@gmail.com", "phone" : "6034758538", "address" : "1035 S Mammoth Rd, Unit 7", "city" : "Manchester", "state" : "NH", "zip" : "03109", "country" : "United States", "adult" : true, "avp_id" : "1016822", "ranking" : { "PoolMAAG" : 3, "PoolCAG" : 17, "PoolCAAG" : 122 }, "shirtSize" : "M", "overallRanking" : { "RankingG" : 3 }, "waivers" : ObjectId("5cc99781babc4817f85c70ba") }, "waivers" : [ { "url" : [ "https://waiverstevie.koptional.com/form/v7/kevin.c.cole@gmail.com/3xrsKWtVlnyjHN2xLhL1XDg3gxUDfuu0D35irIwZ" ], "message" : [ "Liability Waiver" ], "has_signed" : [ true ], "signatureUrl" : [ "https://s3.amazonaws.com/formsign.storage/public/signed/alpoVABWf4jIFERmaXj8fwhlJ1sToMRF3URjz6mB.pdf" ], "email" : [ "kevin.c.cole@gmail.com" ] }, { "url" : [ "https://waiverstevie.koptional.com/form/v7/kevin.c.cole@gmail.com/3xrsKWtVlnyjHN2xLhL1XDg3gxUDfuu0D35irIwZ" ], "message" : [ "Liability Waiver" ], "has_signed" : [ true ], "signatureUrl" : [ "https://s3.amazonaws.com/formsign.storage/public/signed/alpoVABWf4jIFERmaXj8fwhlJ1sToMRF3URjz6mB.pdf" ], "email" : [ "kevin.c.cole@gmail.com" ] } ] }
{ "_id" : { "id" : ObjectId("5cc99b48babc4817f85c70fd"), "email" : "coachcurci@gmail.com" }, "buyer" : [ "coachcurci@gmail.com" ], "event" : "COED A", "field" : "Main", "net" : null, "team" : null, "player" : { "shirtSize" : null, "avp_id" : 1010562, "adult" : true, "zip" : "19054", "state" : "pa", "city" : "levittown", "address" : "9071 millcreek rd ", "phone" : "2152084791", "email" : "coachcurci@gmail.com", "last" : "Curci", "first" : "Jacquelyn", "_id" : ObjectId("5ccaf0263a2bba2ca0f83748"), "waivers" : ObjectId("5cc99b48babc4817f85c70fe"), "completed" : true, "country" : "US", "signed" : false, "shirt_size" : "N/A" }, "waivers" : [ { "url" : [ "https://waiverstevie.koptional.com/form/v7/coachcurci@gmail.com/eCSHwcikcmGP4DaxebeX8toP85MzlSptzvrsSCzt" ], "message" : [ "Liability Waiver" ], "has_signed" : [ true ], "signatureUrl" : [ "https://s3.amazonaws.com/formsign.storage/public/signed/lnaeaOZA2g665YYRDbg4f8zV2ZX2fEz70pI3Gx2I.pdf" ], "email" : [ "coachcurci@gmail.com" ] } ] }
{ "_id" : { "id" : ObjectId("5cc99b48babc4817f85c70fd"), "email" : "jkoodathil@gmail.com" }, "buyer" : [ "coachcurci@gmail.com" ], "event" : "COED A", "field" : "Main", "net" : null, "team" : null, "player" : { "shirtSize" : null, "overallRanking" : { "Ranking" : 5 }, "avp_id" : 1079367, "adult" : true, "zip" : "19020", "state" : "pa", "city" : "bensalem ", "address" : "2139 joshua rd ", "phone" : "+1 (267) 581-7523", "email" : "jkoodathil@gmail.com", "last" : "Koodathil", "first" : "James", "_id" : ObjectId("5ccaf0263a2bba2ca0f83747"), "waivers" : ObjectId("5cc99b48babc4817f85c7100"), "completed" : true, "country" : "US", "signed" : false, "shirt_size" : "N/A" }, "waivers" : [ { "url" : [ "https://waiverstevie.koptional.com/form/v7/jkoodathil@gmail.com/jhOxsMP9ebTkhzTEaxCeiWk6HJPEtFQCrZ7nLiNz" ], "message" : [ "Liability Waiver" ], "has_signed" : [ true ], "signatureUrl" : [ "https://s3.amazonaws.com/formsign.storage/public/signed/tcbxdipuqSvculgiKkNpis6fJGx4cDkhGtSbh22T.pdf" ], "email" : [ "jkoodathil@gmail.com" ] } ] }
{ "_id" : { "id" : ObjectId("5cc99b5ebabc4817f85c7105"), "email" : "beccas.edventure@gmail.com" }, "buyer" : [ "jmlaughman@gmail.com" ], "event" : "COED A", "field" : "Main", "net" : null, "team" : null, "player" : { "overallRanking" : { "Ranking" : 5 }, "shirtSize" : "XS", "avp_id" : "1079953", "adult" : true, "country" : "United States", "zip" : "17257", "state" : "PA", "city" : "Shippensburg", "address" : "23 Feather Dr", "phone" : "3019919314", "email" : "beccas.edventure@gmail.com", "last" : "Morgan", "first" : "Rebecca", "completed" : true, "waivers" : ObjectId("5cc99b5ebabc4817f85c7107") }, "waivers" : [ { "url" : [ "https://waiverstevie.koptional.com/form/v7/beccas.edventure@gmail.com/jI9L3TG7BHIFyzBoL7dV1ZhSaBxSzKFQYboM4uDj" ], "message" : [ "Liability Waiver" ], "has_signed" : [ true ], "signatureUrl" : [ "https://s3.amazonaws.com/formsign.storage/public/signed/Jbe9sBWVLukgiKkUGdCWoOF4NiUjyb9TPlU0GhW2.pdf" ], "email" : [ "beccas.edventure@gmail.com" ] } ] }
{ "_id" : { "id" : ObjectId("5cc99b5ebabc4817f85c7105"), "email" : "jmlaughman@gmail.com" }, "buyer" : [ "jmlaughman@gmail.com" ], "event" : "COED A", "field" : "Main", "net" : null, "team" : null, "player" : { "overallRanking" : { "Ranking" : 5 }, "shirtSize" : "M", "avp_id" : "1080148", "adult" : true, "country" : "US", "zip" : "17257", "state" : "PA", "city" : "Shippensburg", "address" : "23 Feather Dr", "phone" : "7177299191", "email" : "jmlaughman@gmail.com", "last" : "Laughman", "first" : "Jonathan", "completed" : true, "waivers" : ObjectId("5cc99b5ebabc4817f85c7106") }, "waivers" : [ { "url" : [ "https://waiverstevie.koptional.com/form/v7/Jmlaughman@gmail.com/5pGu62Cuio0pV8Pf7ZieaV2Hc0Y1c82XtoKsGdCo" ], "message" : [ "Liability Waiver" ], "has_signed" : [ true ], "signatureUrl" : [ "https://s3.amazonaws.com/formsign.storage/public/signed/nJnjHtOCrEDOqSAShDvoFrQQ2kCgRLAEGEX71yI5.pdf" ], "email" : [ "Jmlaughman@gmail.com" ] } ] }];
  displayedColumns = ["event", "field", "player", "signed", "waiver", "sendwaiver"];
 
  signed;
  unsigned;
  dummies;
  size: number;

  constructor() {
    
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.pages = this.adminService.getJuliePages();
    //console.log(this.pages);
   
    //this.adminService.GetUnsignedWaivers()
    //.subscribe((data: any) => {
  
    // FILTER THE DATA TO GET COUNTS OF EACH
    // I want to filter the data to show all missing partners
      this.dummies = this.data.filter((x: any) => {
        return x.player.email === "dummypartner@pottstown.com";
      });
      // filter the data to show who has not signed the waiver
      this.unsigned = this.data.filter((x: any) => {
          return x.waivers.has_signed === false;
      });
      // filter the data to show who has signed the waiver
      this.signed = this.data.filter((x: any) => {
          return x.waivers.has_signed === true;
      });
      console.log(this.dummies);
      console.log(this.unsigned);
      console.log(this.signed);
      this.players = this.data;
      this.players.forEach((p) => {
        p.waivers =
            p.waivers.map( w => {
              if (w.signatureUrl.length > 0) {
                w.url = w.signatureUrl;
                w.message = "View Waiver";
              }
                return w;
            });
      });

    console.log("dummies" + this.dummies + "signed", this.signed, "unsigned", this.unsigned);
    this.size = this.players.length;
    console.log(this.players);
  });
}


}
```

```css
.tab-selected {
  color: #fff; /*your  text color */
  background: navy; /* your background color*/
}
.mat-table {
  border: 0px solid black;
  
  .mat-cell {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: left;

    .mat-cell {
      min-height: 60px;
      border-bottom: 0px solid grey;

      &:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="/app/admin"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Players ({{players?.length}})</ion-title>
    <ion-subtitle>Signed: {{signed?.length}} Unsigned: {{unsigned?.length}} Dummies: {{dummies?.length}}</ion-subtitle>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <mat-table class="players-table mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="players">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="event">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Event</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let player">{{player.event}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
      
        <ng-container matColumnDef="field">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Field</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell class="field-cell"
                      *matCellDef="let player">{{player.field}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>      
        <ng-container matColumnDef="player">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Player</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell class="player-cell" *matCellDef="let player"><a href="mailto:{{player.player.email}}">{{player.player.first}} {{player.player.last}}</a>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="signed">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Signed? </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let player">
              <ng-container *ngFor="let waiver of player.waivers">
                {{waiver.has_signed}}
              </ng-container>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="waiver">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Waiver </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let player">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let waiver of player.waivers">
                  <a href="{{waiver.url}}">{{waiver.message}}</a>
                </ng-container>
              </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
  
          <ng-container matColumnDef="sendwaiver">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Send Waivers</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell class="sendwaiver-cell" *matCellDef="let player">
              <ion-button (click)="adminWaiverSend(player)" *ngIf="!player.waivers.has_signed"> Send Waivers
                </ion-button>
          </mat-cell>  
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" (click)="onRowClicked(row)"></mat-row>
        
    </mat-table> 
</ion-content>
```

I have the following data structure in my array of objects:

```
[{
event: string,
day: string,
player: {
    first: string,
    last: string,
    email: string
},
waivers: [{
    url: string,
    signatureUrl: string,
    email: string,
    message: string
}],
_id: {
  id: objectID,
  email: string
},
...]
```

In my component, I want to filter the data so I can display a count of three different things:

1. `this.dummies` will filter the results to show any records with a `player.email` of `dummypartner@pottstown.com`
2. `unsigned` will filter the results by the waivers array's `has_signed` property.  It should be set to `false`
3. `signed` should filter the results by the nested array waivers' `has_signed` property being equal to `true`

---

```
this.adminService.GetUnsignedWaivers()
.subscribe((data: []) => {
   this.dummies = data.filter(x => {
      return x.player.email === "dummypartner@pottstown.com";
   });
this.unsigned = data.filter(x => {
   x.waivers.filter(w => {
      return w.has_signed === false;
   });
});
this.signed = data.filter(x => {
   x.waivers.filter(w => {
      return w.has_signed === true;
   });
});
this.players = data;
this.players.forEach((p) => {
   p.waivers = p.waivers.map( w => {
      if (w.signatureUrl.length > 0) {
         w.url = w.signatureUrl;
         w.message = "View Waiver";
      }
      return w;
   });
});
```

I tried to get the above to display as code, but it wouldn't work!  :(

The results of my initial query display nicely, but the counts of the filtered data don't display and log as undefined in the console.

How can I do this?

Edited to add the console.log of data:
[image]

Looking at this, I can see why it might not work, but I don't know how to group the waivers in my aggregation so the values aren't in arrays (because they are not arrays, they are strings).

My backend aggregation query:

```
    Registration.aggregate([
      {$unwind: "$players"},
    {$unwind:"$players.waivers"},
    {$lookup:{
      from:"waiverrecipients",
      localField: "players.waivers",
      foreignField:"_id",
      as:"waivers"
    }},
    {$group: 
      {
        "_id":{"id": "$_id","email": "$players.email"},
        "buyer": {"$first": "$users"},
        "event": {"$first": "$event"},
        "field": {"$first": "$field"},
        "net": {"$first": "$net"},
        "team": {"$first": "$team"},
        "player": { "$first": "$players" },
        "waivers": {"$push":{
          "url": "$waivers.url",
          "message": "$waivers.message",
          "has_signed": "$waivers.has_signed",
          "signatureUrl": "$waivers.signatureUrl",
          "email": "$waivers.email"
        } }}},
    {$sort: 
      {
        "event": 1,
        "_id.id": 1,
        "_id.email": 1,
  }}
  ])
```

Comment: Can you specify what exactly is returning `undefined` and where you log it?

Comment: kindly provide a demo.

Comment: @favdev, I console.logged each filtered variable (dummies, unsigned, and signed).

Comment: @Divneet, I added some code, but since it's part of an entire app, not adding all my services etc breaks it.  You can get an idea of what I'm trying to do, now, though.

Comment: Is that the exact data you are using? Because it is not syntactically correct (no commas between objects, angular doesn't use 'ObjectId') also some strange stuff like array brackets around the 'has_signed' property

Comment: Typescript gives me this error in vscode about the has_signed variable `This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'boolean[]' and 'boolean' have no overlap.ts(2367)`

Comment: @favdev It's code I copied from mongo shell after running the query my service would have run so I could show you what data I was getting.

Comment: @favdev that may be why one of my other code issues didn't work using has_signed === true or false, but it did work if I checked that the length of signatureUrl was greater than 0!  :)

Comment: Are you able to `console.log(this.data)` and show me a screenshot of the data received in the `subscribe` method?

Comment: @favdev I updated my post to include the screenshot of the console.log as well as my aggregation query, as I think that might be the problem.  I don't know how to get my string values in the waivers array to be actual strings and not in an array value.

Comment: @mcadio Can you better explain the values of unsigned and signed? Or can you tell us for those data that you published what would be the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need filtered arrays and counts, you could iterate over the `data` array once with a `forEach` and check for each condition, pushing to the appropriate array if any are met. Then you have three filtered arrays and can call the `.length` method on any of them to get the count.

```js
// app.component.ts

let players: any[] = [];
let dummies: any[] = [];
let unsigned: any[] = [];
let signed: any[] = [];

this.adminService.GetUnsignedWaivers().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
  data.forEach(x => {
    if (x.player.email === 'dummypartner@pottstown.com') {
      dummies.push(x);
    }

    x.waivers.forEach(waiver => {
      if (waiver.has_signed[0] === true) {
        signed.push(waiver);
      } else {
        unsigned.push(waiver);
      }

      if (waiver.signatureUrl.length > 0) {
        waiver.url = waiver.signatureUrl;
        waiver.message = "View Waiver";
      }
    }); // waiver forEach
  }); // data forEach

  this.players = data;
}); // subscribe
```

If you would rather use the `filter` method:

```js
// app.component.ts

let players: any[];
let dummies: any[];
let unsigned: any[] = [];
let signed: any[] = [];

this.adminService.GetUnsignedWaivers().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
  let updatedData = data.map(x => {
    x.waivers.forEach(waiver) {
      if (waiver.signatureUrl.length > 0) {
        waiver.url = waiver.signatureUrl;
        waiver.message = "View Waiver";
      }
    });
    return x;
  }); // map

  this.dummies = updatedData.filter(x => {
    x.player.email === 'dummypartner@pottstown.com';
  }); // filter

  updatedData.forEach(x => {
    unsigned = unsigned.concat(x.waivers.filter(w => !w.has_signed[0]));
    signed = signed.concat(x.waivers.filter(w => w.has_signed[0]));
  }); // forEach

  this.players = updatedData;
}); // subscribe
```

Note that since you are using Material Table, you can add a filter with little code:

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
// app.component.ts

applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Model

```
[{
event: string,
day: string,
player: {
    first: string,
    last: string,
    email: string
},
waivers: [{
    url: string,
    signatureUrl: string,
    email: string,
    message: string
}],
_id: {
  id: objectID,
  email: string
},
...]
```

### Expectations

- this.dummies will filter the results to show any records with a player.email of dummypartner@pottstown.com
- unsigned will filter the results by the waivers array's has_signed property. It should be set to false
- signed should filter the results by the nested array waivers' has_signed property being equal to true

### Code

```
this.dummies = data
  .filter(item => item.player.email === 'dummypartner@pottstown.com');

this.unsigned = data
  .filter(item => item.waivers.some(waiver => !waiver.has_signed));

this.signed = data
  .filter(item => item.waivers.some(waiver => !!waiver.has_signed));
```

This should be waaaay enough for your needs. I don't get why you have made so much complicated code !

[`Array.prototype.some` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 1):

In you component code there is mismatch between what you filter for and the data structure itself. For example:

```ts
this.dummies = this.data.filter((x: any) => {
  // `x` does not have a `player` property based on `this.data` structure
  // The same holds true for all other filter predicates in the file
  return x.player.email === "dummypartner@pottstown.com";
});
```

In your second try the problem lies in how you filter your data...

```ts
this.unsigned = data.filter(x => {
  x.waivers.filter(w => {
    return w.has_signed === false;
});
```

The outer filter function does not return, hence the return value is `undefined`, which is false-y by JS standards. Your `unsigned` array is always empty because the filter predicate returns a false-y statement no matter what.

Also, your data structure does not contain definition for `has_signed`. Are you certain it is always present? If `has_signed` is not present in the data object, `w.has_signed` is `undefined` and `w.has_signed === false` returns `false`. You can either opt not to use type-safe comparison (`==` instead of `===`), or use JS implicit type conversion capabilities by returning `!w.has_signed`.

So, I would re-do your filtering like this (apply the same logic to the `signed` filtering):

```ts
// If you want all objects from `data` where at least one object from `wavers` has not signed
this.unsigned = data.filter(x => x.waivers.some(w => !w.has_signed));
// ^^ With no curly braces the result of the single statement is also the return value

// If you want all the objects from `waivers` with false-y `has_signed`
this.unsigned = data.reduce((x, acc) => [...acc, ...x.waivers.filter(w => !w.has_signed)], []);
```

As for the last part, it is not recommendable to mutate data that you already stored somewhere else. I would suggest making a shallow copy of the objects, like so:

```ts
this.players = data.map(p => ({
  ...p,
  waivers: p.waivers.map(w => 
    w.signatureUrl.length > 0
      ? { ...w, url: w.signatureUrl, message: "View Waiver" }
      : w
  )
}));
```

Hope this helps a little! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I created the situation with express and mongo. I have inserted the data and made a simple query. Something like this:

```
function getPlayers(req, res) {
    ObjectModel.find( (err, data)  => {
        if ( err ) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: err
            });
        }
        return res.status(200).send({
            data
        });
    })

}
```

You must modify the service to return an array:

```
  GetUnsignedWaivers() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url + '/getPlayers').pipe(
      flatMap( data => data.data ),
      toArray()
    );
  }
```

So you guarantee that you have an array of items.
Then you can subscribe:

```
this.adminService.GetUnsignedWaivers().subscribe( (data) => {
      this.dummies = data.filter(item => {
        if (item.player) {
          return item.player.email === 'dummypartner@pottstown.com';
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
      data.forEach( (item, idx) => {
        let flag = false;
        if (item.waivers) {
          item.waivers.forEach(x => {
            if (!x.has_signed[0]) {
              flag = true;
            }
          });
          if (flag) {
            this.unsigned.push(item);
          } else {
            this.signed.push(item);
          }
        }
      });
      console.log(this.dummies);
      console.log(this.unsigned);
      console.log(this.signed);
    });
```

I hope help you